# To show user defined exception messages to the end client using rollback exception strategy in mule

Tags: mule

i want to know how to display our own exception messages to the end client using rollback exception strategy.I have displayed my own message using catch exception block.The code is as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-  tracking-ee.xsd">
<http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" proxyHostname="" proxyUsername="" proxyPassword="" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS"/>
<flow name="TestExampleFlow1" doc:name="TestExampleFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:3030/gdsLoginReqTest" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <cxf:proxy-service namespace="http://tlocalhost:8080/gdsLogin" service="GBDSService" payload="body" wsdlLocation="service/GBDSService.wsdl" doc:name="SOAP" />
    <cxf:proxy-client payload="body"  doc:name="SOAP" />
    <!-- <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String" /> -->
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://uds-uat2.bankofamerica.com/uds/services/GBDSService" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" />
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="catch Exception Strategy">          
    <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />
    <custom-transformer class="com.bac.gwb.credit.csb.exception.CustomExceptionHandler" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />          
</catch-exception-strategy>
 </flow>
```

the class CustomExceptionHandler.java is

```
import org.mule.api.ExceptionPayload;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.message.ExceptionMessage;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;
public class CustomExceptionHandler  extends AbstractMessageTransformer  {
public CustomExceptionHandler() {
    setName("CustomExceptionHandler");
}
@Override
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
        throws TransformerException {
    /* ExceptionMessage exceptionMessage = (ExceptionMessage)message.getExceptionPayload();*/
     ExceptionPayload exceptionMessage=message.getExceptionPayload();
     String t=exceptionMessage.getMessage();


        String outputMessage = "<soap:Fault xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">  <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>An unexpected error has occured. Please contact your service desk and quote this error </faultstring> </soap:Fault>";
        return outputMessage;
}
}
```

This was working with catch exception strategy.I want to make  it workout with rollback exception strategy.

Answer (score 0):

apply `<rollback-exception-strategy />` the same way you did with the catch exception strategy. http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Rollback+Exception+Strategy

Comment: i had done the process using rollback exception strategy.But it was not working in this case.as per my knowledge rollback exception strategies are used when inbound endpoints are transactional.The transactional endpoints are vm,jms,jdbc.I need a simple working example using vm transactional inbound endpoint

Comment: You're right, the rollback exception strategy is commonly used for transactions. However if you open the link I sent, it can also be used to catch unhandled exceptions. If you need to catch a specific exception with the rollback strategy, use a `when` attribute. If you must use VMs then insert them between the HTTP inbound and outbound.

Comment: Thank you Bernard.i need one clarification regarding VM end point.We can insert them in between http endpoints.Is there any possibility to replace http endpoint with VM endpoint.

Comment: as per you suggestion i had inserted VM after http inbound endpoint.In the another flow i kept vm with the same queue path and added the transaction attributes such as type action and time in it.In the second flow i added rollback exception block.when an exception occured control is going to rollback exception block and from there it is throwing an exception as

Comment: ERROR 2014-02-13 15:51:51,030 [[simple_project].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.RollbackMessagingExceptionStrategy: Failed to dispatch message to error queue after it failed to process.  This may cause message loss.Logging Message here: Please help me how to resolve it

Comment: According to the error log, the exception is being handled by the rollback exception strategy, which is good since that is what you asked for. Basically, in your case it doesn't make a difference using a catch strategy or a rollback strategy, so the exception you have now must be a result of the VMs you just put in. Make sure your flow is constructed properly.